# SWT: JavaCocoaComponent compatiblity mode doesn't allow application to exit cleanly

Tags: java, macos, swt

I have a SWT application running on **Mac(10.6.8)**. The SWT version I am using is **swt-4.2.2-cocoa-macosx-x86_64.zip**. My application doesn't exit properly when I call `parent.getShell().close()` , the UI disappears from the screen but the icon remains in the dock and hence it hasn't terminated cleanly.

I don't want to use System.exit(0) as I am doing some background processing even after the application closes in certain cases.

Is this due to the "JavaCocoaComponent compatiblity mode-Enabled" message I get when I launch my application.

How can I avoid this message and make my application exit cleanly?

I have tried using the swt-4.3 jar and ended up with the same result.

**Note: I am also facing this issue when I run my application(jar) outside eclipse.**

Any help provided will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

- Java Version Used: 1.6 update 51
- Eclipse Version Used: Juno SR 2

Other jars used in my application

- json_simple-1.1.jar
- org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6
- org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6
- org.eclipse.jface_3.6

Comment: If you have background threads running which are not marked as `daemons` the program will keep running until these threads terminate.

Comment: I am not able to close my application cleanly even when no background threads are running. This seems to be an issue with the SWT and/or Java. When I run my same code on a newer Mac 10.8.3 with Java 1.7u45 and the same swt version jar, it exits cleanly in all the scenarios.Unfortunately 1.7 is not supported on 10.6.8